# Overlay on image constrained by max-width and max-height

Tags: html, css

See jsFiddle example I have below. I have an image that needs to be vertically and/or horizontally aligned inside a container. That image is constrained by either max-height or max-width as well. I'd like to overlay a "duration" in the bottom right corner of the image (not the container). Can't get anything working and could use some help.

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/yuf2de5z/1/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="thumbnail-container">
  <div class="image-container">
    <img src="http://iss.ku.edu/sites/iss.ku.edu/files/images/galleries/video.bmp"/>
    <span class="duration">00:00:30</span>
  </div>
</div>

<br/><br/>

<div class="thumbnail-container">
  <div class="image-container">
    <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-photo/sky--horizontal_19-121673.jpg"/>
    <span class="duration">00:00:30</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.thumbnail-container {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  text-align: center; 
  margin: 1em 0;
  line-height: 150px;
}

.image-container {
  position: relative;
}

.image-container img {
  vertical-align: middle;
  max-width: 300px;
  max-height: 150px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use flex, very helpfull here:

```css
.thumbnail-container {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  text-align: center; 
  margin: 1em 0;
  line-height: 150px;
  display:flex;
}

.image-container {
  position: relative;
  margin:auto;
}

.image-container img {
  display:block;
  max-width: 300px;
  max-height: 150px;
}

.duration {
  color: green;
  position: absolute;
  line-height:1.2em;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="thumbnail-container">
  <div class="image-container">
    <img src="http://iss.ku.edu/sites/iss.ku.edu/files/images/galleries/video.bmp"/>
    <span class="duration">00:00:30</span>
  </div>
</div>

<br/><br/>

<div class="thumbnail-container">
  <div class="image-container">
    <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-photo/sky--horizontal_19-121673.jpg"/>
    <span class="duration">00:00:30</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

`display:inline-block` too (or eventually inline-table)

```css
.thumbnail-container {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  text-align: center; 
  margin: 1em 0;
  line-height: 150px;
}

.image-container {
  position: relative;
  display:inline-block;/* inline-table works too if you  images in cells and row to center here*/
  vertical-align:middle;
}

.image-container img {
  display:block;
  max-width: 300px;
  max-height: 150px;
}

.duration {
  color: green;
  position: absolute;
  line-height:1.2em;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="thumbnail-container">
  <div class="image-container">
    <img src="http://iss.ku.edu/sites/iss.ku.edu/files/images/galleries/video.bmp"/>
    <span class="duration">00:00:30</span>
  </div>
</div>

<br/><br/>

<div class="thumbnail-container">
  <div class="image-container">
    <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-photo/sky--horizontal_19-121673.jpg"/>
    <span class="duration">00:00:30</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @KevinM the idea is to have image-container to wrap/shrink on its content :) flex makes it if child is margin-auto without flex rules, inline-block,inline-table and table too, but table won't stand on baseline ...

Answer (score 0):

Can you add code around the image and duration? If so:

```css
.thumbnail-container {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  text-align: center; 
  margin: 1em 0;
  line-height: 150px;
}

.image-container {
  position: relative;
}

.image-container img {
  vertical-align: middle;
  max-width: 300px;
  max-height: 150px;
}

.duration {
  color: green;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

/* additional styles */
.this-is-to-get-a-positioning-context {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid green;
  display: inline-block;
}

.this-is-to-get-a-positioning-context {
  line-height: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="thumbnail-container">
  <div class="image-container">
    <span class="this-is-to-get-a-positioning-context">
      <img src="http://iss.ku.edu/sites/iss.ku.edu/files/images/galleries/video.bmp"/>
      <span class="duration">00:00:30</span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>

<br/><br/>

<div class="thumbnail-container">
  <div class="image-container">
    <span class="this-is-to-get-a-positioning-context">
      <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-photo/sky--horizontal_19-121673.jpg"/>
      <span class="duration">00:00:30</span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```